# Why is the following sql query in php not working?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I am new to php and Sql. And i am trying to get data from a HTML form and insert it into database.

My html code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And my php code is as follows:

```
<?php
//Connecting to sql db.
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","my_db");
//Sending form data to sql db.
$query = "INSERT INTO  person ('name' 'email') VALUES ('"
.$_POST['name']
."','"
.$_POST['email']
."');";

mysqli_query($connect, $query);
?>
```

I have created a database in phpMyAdmin but my query doesn't work and the tables do not get updated. What am i doing wrong?..How to correct it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

forgot a comma between name and email

Also, change the sngle quotes to backticks..

so this..

```
 "INSERT INTO  `person` ('name' 'email')
```

becomes this

```
 "INSERT INTO  `person` (`name`, `email`)
```

Comment: you need to also change the single quotes to backticks as well. that's the button below the esc key.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `'` to differentiate column name. Instead you can use `` ` `` or nothing in column name.

You can use following syntax;

`$query = "INSERT INTO  person (name, email) VALUES ('$_POST[name]', '$_POST[email]');";`

Answer (score 0):

Remove single Quotes and add back ticks:

`$query = "INSERT INTO  person (`name`,`email`) VALUES ('`

Answer (score 0):

try mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","my_db") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

make sure the right connection

Comment: it would be `mysqli_connect_error()`, not `mysqli_error()` :p

Answer (score 0):

Use this query in your code 
Hope it will help you

```
$query = "INSERT INTO person VALUES('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use something like PDO for database actions. It's better in terms of legibleness and security.

Here is a quick tutorial

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Insert-and-Update-Statement-Use-Prepared-Statement-P552.html

Answer (score 0):

It is enough
**$query="INSERT INTO person(name,email)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]')";**

Comment: Adding POST variables directly into an SQL string is incredibly bad practice - I suggest you look up SQL injection.